# AutoCompleteTextView selection background color change

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to remove the light white color after selecting it from the drop-down menu.

[image]

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/force_localization_layout"
            style="@style/ForceLocalizationStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Force Localization"
            android:textColorHint="@color/edit_text_box"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppTheme.TextInputEditText.Outlined"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:boxBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
            app:boxStrokeColor="@color/edit_text_box"
            app:endIconTint="@color/edit_text_box"
            app:hintTextColor="@color/edit_text_box">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/force_localization"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:inputType="textAutoComplete"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

I need something like this after selection.

[image]